# Perform action after all *ngFor list variable entries have been displayed

Tags: angular

In an Angular 8 application, I have a container element containing `*ngFor` generated elements. I have the container's CSS property `overflow: auto` as I aim for it having a fixed height disregarding the number of the `*ngFor` generated elements in it.

I want to programmatically scroll to the bottom of the container executing `containerElement.scrollTo(0, containerElement.scrollHeight);`  after the `*ngFor` items are all generated, so that the container have its `containerElement.scrollHeight` calculated.

The problem is that if I use the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook, it is triggered once, but it doesn't guarantee that the `*ngFor` items will be rendered (it always fires before that in my case). If I use `AfterViewChecked` hook, it works, but it is fired so many times, that I think that there must be a better solution where I use event handler that fires exactly once, after the `*ngFor` is guaranteed to have been executed on the DOM.

Thanks to all that will think on a solution of this problem!

UPDATE with this workaround solution:
Because of no answers, I decided to apply a workaround. I did something like the following: set `id` attributes to the `*ngFor` generated elements, and test for the existence of the last one in the DOM certain number of times, after the entries are fetched from the server:

In a controller

```
private loopEntries = [];
private scrollInterval;

async ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.loopEntries = await this.getFromServer();
  if (typeof this.loopEntries !== 'undefined' && this.loopEntries.length) {
    let lastLoopElem = null,
        numTries = 0; // try certain number of times before giving up

    this.scrollInterval = setInterval(() => {
      lastLoopElem = document.querySelector('#index_' + (this.loopEntries.length - 1));
      if (lastLoopElem) { // element is found in the DOM !!!
        const containerElement = document.querySelector('.container');
        containerElement.scrollTo(0, containerElement.scrollHeight);
      }

      if (lastLoopElem || numTries > 10) {
        clearInterval(this.scrollInterval); // clear interval in all the cases
      }
      numTries++;
    }, 50);
  }
  ...
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.scrollInterval); // clear interval on navigate away
}
```

In a template:

```
<section class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let item of loopEntries; index as i" [id]="index_' + i">

  </div>
</section>
```

I know it's a bit verbose and hacky, but I offer it to your attention because of lack of better solution at this time. It's similar to using setTimeout, but has more chance to succeed because it tries various times. Usually it succeeds on the first try.

Comment: Have you considered using a slight delay inside the hook (i.e. `setTimeout()`) to ensure the page is loaded? Obviously, this wouldn't be fullproof, but it would render correctly in the vast majority of cases, so long as the delay is correctly timed... Otherwise, you could use a reactive solution such as RxJS.

Comment: Yes, @NathanToulbert, the `setTimeout()` is of course the first thing one could think of, but the idea was to explore for any Angular built in solutions to achieve it. After all, if it turns out that there is no other way, then as you pointed out I'll use an observable.